# Returning JSON from Ruby on Rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, arrays, json, ruby

I inherit a RoR api, that provides that to a angular app.  I am new to RoR and I am having difficulties with the way the api returns data in json.

```
def getLocations
    location = params[:name]
    query = "select * from  view_locations where lower(location_name) like lower('#{location}%') limit 4 "
    propAll = Property.connection.select_all(query)
    respond_to do |format|
      if !propAll.blank?
         format.json { render json: {status:"ok", data:propAll}}
      else
        format.json { render json: {status:"error"}}
      end
    end
  end
```

This code returns this array:

[{"location_name":"Nuevo León","id":"19","quantity":"5988","type":"State"},{"location_name":"Naucalpan de Juárez, México","id":"09","quantity":"131","type":"City"},{"location_name":"Nayarit","id":"18","quantity":"91","type":"State"},{"location_name":"Nacajuca, Tabasco","id":"013","quantity":"20","type":"City"}]

Is there any way that I could return the JSON instead of an array? 
If its not possible, how should I use the returned array in Angularjs, right now we are going through every array element and pushing it in another array .

Thanks, for any help provided
Alberto

Comment: The data was sent to client side as a JSON only. But what Data-structure you are looking for instead of an Array? Data format which was sent is correct, but the way it is fetched from DB is not Rails way. :)

Comment: I've used asp.net web api, and I would get this {"location_name":"Nuevo León","id":"19","quantity":"5988","type":"State"},{"location_name":"Naucalpan de Juárez, México","id":"09","quantity":"131","type":"City"},{"location_name":"Nayarit","id":"18","quantity":"91","type":"State"},{"location_name":"Nacajuca, Tabasco","id":"013","quantity":"20","type":"City"} I would use it, without any transformation on the client, vm.locations = response.locations, and then use vm.locations in a select

Comment: That is not valid. You got a list of objects, and you need array in this case. Otherwise syntax is not valid. How can you send those without wrapping them in an Array..? `{a: 1}, {b: 2}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: you can use response.data.foreach(function(item){}) at the success callback for reach them one by one

Comment: Got it Arup, thanks